# Sanitize html, where to sanitize

Tags: functions, html, sanitization

I have a function that returns an style=".." html attribute. I am not sure how to sanitize. Here is the code:

functions.php

```
function zz_style($properties, $values) {

    $styles_array = array();
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($properties as $property) {

        if ($values[$i] != null) {

            $styles_array[] = $property . ':' . $values[$i];
        }
        $i++;

    }

    return 'style="' . implode(";", $styles_array) . '" ';

}
```

index.php

```
$zz = get_theme_mod('zz');

<div <?php echo zz_style(array('color'),array($zz['colorA'])); ?>></div>
```

Options I can think of:

```
wp_kses(zz_style(...));

zz_style(array('color'),array(sanitize_hex_color($zz['colorA'])));

wp_kses(zz_style(array('color'),array(sanitize_hex_color($zz['colorA']))));
```

So my question is how should I sanitize this?
Sanitize it in the functions.php or in the index.php?

Comment: Where is the information coming from?  The database or user input?

Comment: It is coming from user input.

Comment: Looking at the code, you have a `$zz = get_theme_mod('zz');` which pulls a setting from the database.  Is that what you want to sanitize?  When I mean user input, I mean data from a form being filled out, or whatever, which you're then going to put into a database.  As a rule, you want to sanitize data going in, and escape it coming out.  So, this is coming *out* right?  [This article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) should help a ton.

Comment: Ok, thanks sorry for the misunderstood. Yes, data will come from Post Metaboxes and Customizer. Ill take a deeper look.

Comment: It says: "Tip: It's best to do the output validation as late as possible, ideally as it's being outputted, as opposed to further up in your script. This way you can always be sure that your data is properly validated/escaped and you don't need to remember if the variable has been previously validated." Should I follow the tip in this case? I can think if the data is not correctly formatted before entering the function then it might return an incorrect value and never appear in the front end.